# Running a program (written in C) in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I'm using Ubuntu.

I wrote a program in C which interacts with a Mysql Database

The compilation process goes smoothly (excepts several warnings) and I get the executable.

How do I run it in Ubuntu?

I mean, I use this command :

```
gcc -o magazzino main_magazzino.c -L/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient
```

How do I run magazzino?

Answer (score 5):

if it is in the current directory, run `./magazzino`

Comment: In other words, you need to 1) run your program from a command line, and also 2) tell the command line *where* the program is located.  Here's a nice, short tutorial on using the Ubuntu command line: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

Answer (score 3):

Usually:

```
./magazzino
```

The dot and slash are to tell the shell that you mean the executable in *this* current directory - otherwise it would search for the program in its $PATH and probably not find it. (Although it's possible to have the current directory in your PATH, this is a bad idea and not recommended for security reasons.)

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
/path/to/magazzino
```

And if your current_folder is same with where magazzino stored use

```
./magazzino
```

Comment: thank you very much...I take this opportunity to ask : if during the compilation process I get several WARNINGS but the file gets generated anyway, does that mean my program is faulty?

Comment: @Margherita - There is no one right answer to that. It depends on the warning how likely you are to get bit by something.  The easiest thing to do is to fix the code and get rid of the warnings.  Peace of mind.

Comment: Depends on the warning, depends on the uses you put your program to. If a warning is "comparison of signed int with unsigned", that will probably not change anything until your logic uses numbers so high that it matters whether the highest bit means one thing or another. On the other hand, if you get the warning "Use of gets() is dangerous", then your program is now guaranteed to contain a security hole. For best results, read all warnings and either change your code or understand why they are irrelevant and then add suppressor #pragmas, so that your compilation output is clean.

Answer (score 0):

In the directory type in,

```
./magazzino
```